# SLASH "/" in front of relative urls in RewriteRule: Correct Syntax?

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, apache2, directory

Given:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com$  
RewriteRule ^$ /de/home [L]
```

Question: examine the slash in front of de:

`/de/home`

`de/home`

What is the difference here and which is more advisable to use?

Comment: There was a typo in my answer: The second path was missing a trailing `/home`. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably no difference in this context, because you are likely to be in the root directory.

Were you not in the root directory, but in a sub-folder like, say,

```
example.com/beta
```

, `de/home` could point to

```
example.com/beta/de/home
```

The starting slash makes sure the URL starts at the root directory, regardless where you are.

Comment: According to [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html), your example would result in `example.com/de/home` because the base url doesn't end with a slash.